# How can I display multiple windows concatenated with cv2 in array form?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python

I am capturing the frames in real time from various cameras. The output of each camera is displayed in a window with cv2.imshow. What I want to achieve now is that all the windows are concatenated forming a grid/matrix, for example, if I have 4 cameras, that the windows show me concatenated in 2x2.

Below I attach the code of what I have. Which allows me to capture the frames of the different cameras that I have, but I am not being able to do the above.

```
cap = []
ret = []
frame = []
final = ""
i = 0

cap.append(cv2.VideoCapture(0))
cap.append(cv2.VideoCapture(1))
cap.append(cv2.VideoCapture(2))

number_cameras = len(cap)

# I initialize values
for x in range(number_cameras):
    ret.append(x)
    frame.append(x)

while(True):

    # I capture frame by frame from each camera
    ret[i], frame[i] = cap[i].read()

    if i == number_cameras-1:

        final = cv2.hconcat([cv2.resize(frame[x], (400, 400)) for x in range(number_cameras)])
        cv2.namedWindow('frame')
        cv2.moveWindow('frame', 0, 0)
        # I show the concatenated outputs
        cv2.imshow('frame', final)

        i = 0

    else:
        i = i + 1

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# I release the cameras
for x in range(number_cameras):
    cap[x].release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a frame out of 4 frames by resizing the frames to half their width and height. Then create an empty frame and fill it according to the resized width and height.

Since I don't currently have 4 cameras I simulating this using a single camera.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        #find half of the width
        w = int(frame.shape[1] * 50 / 100)
        #find half of the height
        h = int(frame.shape[0] * 50 / 100)
        dim = (w, h)
        #resize the frame to half it size
        frame =cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        #create an empty frame
        output = np.zeros((h*2,w*2,3), np.uint8)
        #place a frame at the top left
        output[0:h, 0:w] = frame
        #place a frame at the top right
        output[0:h, w:w * 2] = frame
        #place a frame at the bottom left
        output[h:h * 2, w:w * 2] = frame
        #place a frame at the bottom right
        output[h:h * 2, 0:w] = frame
        cv2.imshow("Output", output)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks but this code does not work for me. I want to do all this in a dynamic way. That is, the user would enter the number of cameras, for example, two, four, six, etc., there would begin the capture of frames and in turn the concatenation in the form of a matrix. What you did is show the captures of the same camera four times in the same window, and all this in a static way, which is the opposite of what I intend to achieve.